# Info-window not getting refreshed: AngularJS and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am struggling a lot with info-windows to show when clicking on custom markers. I finally got to show them, but the result is not quite correct. In fact, clicking on the first marker, the info box shows its content correctly. However, clicking on any other marker after the first causes the info-window to show but with the previous content.
This happens for any marker: first clicked works, successors show the previous content.

Code:

```
<map data-ng-model="mymap" zoom="4" center="[38.50, -95.00]" style="heigth:375px">

          <info-window id="foo">
          <div ng-non-bindable="">

            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </info-window>

          <marker ng-repeat="item in list" 
          position="[{{item.coordinates}}]" itemTitle="{{item.name}}" 
          icon="./images/i.png" on-click="showInfoWindow('bar')" />     

        <info-window id="bar">
        <div class="infowindowtexttitle">{{this.itemTitle}}</div>
        </div>
        </info-window>
```

Comment: I see you are hardcoding 'bar' in your showInfoWindow call, are you meant to be doing that?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I need to show the itemTitle in the info-window and I am putting several markes on the map, each having its title store in the itemTitle field.

Comment: Ok, can you update your code above and show what showInfoWindow is doing?

Comment: I didn't implement it, it is part of the google library

Comment: Also, how can I pass a angularjs managed variable (e.g. item.name) to the showInfoWindow on-click handler?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by:
1) Creating a div around marker AND info-window
2) Moving ng-repeat into the new div
3) Using the iterating variable (item) rather than this.